# How to remove duplicate elements in an array of struct and print the output

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to remove duplicates from data read from a file and stored in an array of struct and print the new unique values to a file

I have a file with x,y values and index,i have read the data from the file and stored it in an array of struct,i want to go through the array and remove duplicate elements(x and y matching)finally print the new unique values to a file.the file i am reading has below data

1. 12  20
2. 20  29
3. 68  87
4. 20  29

My goal is to read the file into an array of struct,remove duplicates and print them to another file.below is my code

```
int store_fixation_point(FILE *fp,int id,struct fixation_point_type fixation_point[],int x, int y);
struct fixation_point_type {
    int id_number;
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main()
{
    int N_list,i,N,j;
    int temp1 = 0;
    float temp2, temp3;

    int id_N0=0;
    FILE *fp_in, *fp_out;
    int fixation_number = 0, x =0, y=0;
    char ch;
    fixation_point_type fixationPoint [MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS];
fp_in = fopen("../data/input.txt", "r");
if (fp_in == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open the input file \n");
    exit(0);
}
fp_out = fopen("../data/output.txt", "w");
if (fp_out == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open the output file \n");
    exit(0);
}

fscanf(fp_in,"%d",&N_list);
i = 0;
do
{
    i++;
    N = 0;
    temp2 = 0;
    temp3 = 0;
    do
    {
        if (fscanf(fp_in, "%d %f %f ", &temp1,&temp2,&temp3) != EOF){
        if (temp2 == -1 && temp2 == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fixationPoint[N].id_number = temp1;
            fixationPoint[N].x = temp2;
            fixationPoint[N].y = temp3;
            N++;
        }
        }
    }while(1);
    store_fixation_point(fp_out,N,fixationPoint,x,y);
            fscanf(fp_in, "%d %d %d", &fixation_number, &x, &y);
            N++;
  for (j=0;j<N;j++)
 {
     printf("%3d %d %d\n",fixationPoint[j].id_number,(int)fixationPoint[j].x,(int)fixationPoint[j].y);
      fprintf(fp_out,"%3d %d %d\n",fixationPoint[j].id_number,(int)fixationPoint[j].x,(int)fixationPoint[j].y);
   }
    printf("------------------------\n");
    fprintf(fp_out,"------------------------\n");
}while(i<N_list);
fclose(fp_in);
fclose(fp_out);
return 0;
}
//function to remove duplicates
int store_fixation_point(FILE *fp,int indexID,struct fixation_point_type fixation_point[],int x, int y)
{
    int i;
    int a =0;
    int index=0;
    fixation_point_type temp[1000];
    if(indexID == 0){
        printf("%d %d %d\n",fixation_point[indexID].id_number, fixation_point[indexID].x,fixation_point[indexID].y);    
    }
    else
    {
        for (i =0; i < indexID; i++){
            if ( (fixation_point[i].x ==x)  && (fixation_point[i].y==y) ){
                a=a+1;
            }   
        }
        if (a==0)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d\n",fixation_point[indexID].id_number, fixation_point[indexID].x,fixation_point[indexID].y);
            fprintf(fp,"%d %d %d \n",fixation_point[indexID].id_number, fixation_point[indexID].x,fixation_point[indexID].y);   
        }
        return indexID;
```

i expect output of unique values e.g

1. 12  20
2. 20  29
3. 68  87

Comment: I was wrong in my comment, but please fix consistent indentation. That's why I made a mistake.

Comment: In reality, you will save yourself quite a bit of copying and shuffling of elements if you check for duplicates during the read and only store unique values rather than reading all x, y values into you array and then deleting them from the array.

Comment: how do i accomplish that David,i think that's more efficient

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to separate the separate parts of your program into separate functions, or procedures. This way each serves as a "black box" whose behavior is encapsulated. The first function is `cmp` which will compare two structures memberwise. Based off this fundamental function, we can then build the bigger function, `remDups` which removes duplicates.

```
/* return 0 if structures are memberwise equal; false otherwise */
int cmp(const struct fixation_point_type *const a, const struct fixation_point_type *const b)
{
   return (a->id_number == b->id_number && a->x == b->x && a->y == b->y);
}

/* removes duplicates in the array arr */
void remDups(struct fixation_point_type arr[], size_t n)
{
    assert(n >= 0);
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    size_t len = n;
    while (--n > 0) {
        /* if this elem. and the previous elem. are equal, shift elements beyond 
           arr[n] into its position */
        if (cmp(arr[n], arr[n-1]) == 0)
            memmove(arr + n - 1, arr + n, sizeof (*arr) * (len-n));
    }
}
```

The `remDups` function uses `memmove` to shift elements, overwriting the duplicate element. The expression `sizeof (*arr) * (len-n)` is the number of bytes in the elements beyond `arr[n]`.

Comment: Not me who DV:d, but I would bet some money it's because it's a code only answer.

Comment: To the downvoter: added comments, fixed typo in code